# spring-cloud-skipper : How to delete and re-deploy a package

Tags: spring-cloud-skipper

I want to redeploy a package but I am getting an error:

> skipper:>package install --package-name sg-cloud-MbakTestworld
>   --package-version 0.0.1 --release-name MbakTestworld --file E:\skipper\apps\MbakTestworld-upgrade-local.yml

Result:

> Release with the name [] already exists and it is not deleted. Details
>   of the error have been omitted. You can use the stacktrace command to
>   print the full stacktrace.

**My yml File:**

```
spec:
  applicationProperties:
    server.port: 8029
    spring.profiles.active: mbakCloud
  deploymentProperties:
    spring.cloud.deployer.memory: 512m
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
skipper:>release delete --release-name MbakTestworld
```

MbakTestworld has been deleted.

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-skipper/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/